# Local minima of a functions

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let the $f(x)$ is a strictly convex function on the $(a,b)$, and $\lim_{x\to a^+}=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to b^-}=\infty$, then exists only one local minima on $(a,b)$.
Is this true?

sorry for my English

Comment: Suppose there was more than one, what would that imply?

Comment: You can comment here.  Use the definition of convexity assuming there are two minima.